# How to pass an array of images for selected multiple images from gallery and display them on another widget in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a grid view and floating button  on main.dart where on tapping floating button I get an option to select multiple images using flutter_multiple_image_picker plugin and pass them to another view .Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a way to maintain state across the widgets (views). One way to do that is with an InheritedWidget. For example https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1

Comment: I am not getting any idea how will I be able to use Inherited widget for this problem.  The problem is within the plugin there's a Done button which navigates to initial page where selected images can be passed.But I need to route to different screen with those selected images .So I was searching for another way !

Answer (score 0):

I have developed MovieMaker-Flutter app which picks videos from the gallery and merge those videos and make a movie.

FAB action button code: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/MovieMaker-Flutter/blob/master/lib/main.dart#L75

Gallery Widget code: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/MovieMaker-Flutter/blob/master/lib/main.dart#L115

Hope you find it helpful. Happy to help you to if still there is any issue.

Comment: Thanks Vipin for your valuable suggestion .

Comment: How did you add the cache.dart dependency ? I am not getting any cache version dependency

Comment: it's a simple caching dart file. You can find it in that repo tree.

Comment: I have tried adding the file for cache.dart file but not working https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart

Comment: I an not using flutter caching feature for now. Built static caching myself: https://github.com/bipinvaylu/MovieMaker-Flutter/blob/master/lib/cache.dart